# How do I convert an upstart job to a systemd service?

Tags: systemd

I have the following upstart job:

```
# hwclock - adjust system clock and timezone
#
# The hwclock task adjusts the system clock when the hardware clock is
# set to localtime (e.g. when dual-booting with Windows), and also
# ensures that the system timezone is set so that timestamps are written
# to FAT devices.

description     "adjust system clock and timezone"

start on starting mountall

task

script
    exec hwclock --systz --utc --noadjfile
end script
```

I would like to switch this to systemd service.

How should `start on starting mountall` be implemented on systemd?

I created the systemd service as below, but I do not know how to do `start on starting mountall`.

```
[Unit]
Description=hwclock
After=
Before=

[Service]
ExecStart=/sbin/hwclock --systz --utc --noadjfile
```

Comment: I think that's where the `Before=` line comes in!

Comment: It's also probably `Type=oneshot`, because hwclock will exit when it's done.

Comment: Check out [systemd for upstart users](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers) and perhaps `After=local-fs.target`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need these lines:

```
Requires=
After=
```

As stated here:

> Requires=: This directive lists any units upon which this unit essentially depends. If the current unit is activated, the units listed here must successfully activate as well, else this unit will fail. These units are started in parallel with the current unit by default.
>
> After=: The units listed in this directive will be started before starting the current unit. This does not imply a dependency relationship and one must be established through the above directives if this is required.

The structure should be:

```
[Unit]
Description=hwclock
Requires= # mountall most happen
After= # mountall should have started before hwclock run

[Service]
Type=oneshort
ExecStart=/sbin/hwclock --systz --utc --noadjfile
```

From [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SystemdForUpstartUsers):

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Upstart stanza | systemd unit file directive | systemd unit file section
               |                             |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
start on       |    Wants, Requires, Before, |
               |    After                    |  Unit 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note: This is for an Ubuntu system but should be similar. See: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html also.